# How to get the values of dynamically input fields and process them in Django views

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, django

I have an input field that can be added dynamically in my template html file. Now, I want to get all those values to process them in the views. However, I am getting only the last value

Any idea on how to grab all the values?

Thank you and here is my code

Html file

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label>Required Skills</label>
                    <div class="input_skills_wrap">
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="internship_skills[]" 
required><button class="btn btn-primary add-more-skill" type="button"><i class="glyphicon 
glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
                        </div>
                   </div>
               </div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //EMPLOYMENT SKILLS
    $(".add-more-skill").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".input_skills_wrap").append('<div><input type="text" class="form-control" 
 name="internship_skills[]" required><button class="btn btn-danger remove-skill" type="button"> 
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button></div>');
    });

    $(".input_skills_wrap").on("click", ".remove-skill", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
   });
</script>
```

views.py

```
def post_internship(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
 
        skills = request.POST['internship_skills[]']
        print(skills)

    return render(request, 'post_internship.html')
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [request.POST.getlist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) instead of access by key because the latter returns only the last item as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.__getitem__):

> QueryDict._ _ getitem_ _(key)
>
> Returns the value for the given key. If
> the key has more than one value, it returns the last value. Raises
> django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError if the key does not
> exist. (This is a subclass of Python’s standard KeyError, so you can
> stick to catching KeyError.)

vs

> QueryDict.getlist(key, default=None)
>
> Returns a list of the data with the requested key. Returns an empty
> list if the key doesn’t exist and default is None. It’s guaranteed to
> return a list unless the default value provided isn’t a list.